# How to remove all featureGroups from a map in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have two maps: map_1 and map_2. I added several featureGroups to each one of them. For example:

```
L.featureGroup({}).addTo(map_1);
```

Besides that, I add the following to each one of the maps. Each one with different information.

```
var layer_control = {
  base_layers : {
     "cartodbpositron" : tile_layer,
  },
     overlays :  {
      ...
  },
};

L.control.layers(
  layer_control.base_layers,
  layer_control.overlays,
  {"autoZIndex": true, "collapsed": true, "position": "topright"}
).addTo(map_1);
```

How can I remove all the featureGroups and the controls from one of the maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating anonymous features, create them in variables that you can reference later when you want to remove them.

```
var myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup({}).addTo(map_1);

var myLayersControl = L.control.layers(
  layer_control.base_layers,
  layer_control.overlays,
  {"autoZIndex": true, "collapsed": true, "position": "topright"}
).addTo(map_1);
```

Then later

```
myFeatureGroup.remove();
myLayersControl.remove();
```